# Bond PDE under an Affine Jump Diffusion model

Tags: bond, jump-diffusion, parabolic-pde

Under the Jump extended Vasicek model, the dynamics of the short rate are as follow :
$$dr_t=\kappa(\theta-r_t)dt+\sigma\sqrt{r_t}\,dW_t+d\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N_t}\,J_i\right)$$
where $N_t$ represents a Poisson process with constant intensity rate $\lambda>0$ and $\{J_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ denotes the magnitudes
of jump, which are assumed to be i.i.d. random variables with distribution $f_J$ independent of $W_t$ and $N_t$. Moreover,$W_t$ is assumed to be independent of $N_t$. In addition the jump sizes $\,J_i$ has an exponential distribution with density:
$${{f}_{J}}(\chi )=\left\{ \begin{matrix}
   \eta {{e}^{-\eta\,\chi}}\,,\,\,\chi >0\,  \\
   0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,,\,\,\,\,o.w.  \\
\end{matrix} \right.$$
where $\eta > 0 $ is an constant. Can some one explain how to find the following parabolic partial integro differential equation for an arbitrage-free price at time $t$ of of a ZC bond of maturity $T$ ? :
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}{{\sigma }^{2}}r\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}P}{\partial {{r}^{2}}}+\kappa (\theta -r)\frac{\partial P}{\partial r}-rP+\lambda \int_{-\infty }^{\infty }{(P(t,r+\chi ,T)-P(t,r,T)d\chi =0}$$
with boundary condition $P(T,r,T)=1$.

Thank you

Comment: Your equation has an error. See the derivation below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(t, r_t, T)$ be the bond price at time $t$, where $0  \leq t \leq T$. Then, by Ito's formula,
\begin{align*}
&\ P(t, r_t, T) \\
=& P(0, r_0, T) + \int_0^t\partial_s P(s, r_s, T) ds + \int_0^t\partial_r P(s, r_{s-}, T) dr_s + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \int_0^t r_s\partial_{rr} P(s, r_s, T)ds\\
& \quad +\sum_{s \leq t}\big[P(s, r_s, T) - P(s, r_{s-}, T) - \partial_r P(s, r_{s-}, T)\Delta r_s\big] \quad (\mbox{where } \Delta r_s=r_s - r_{s-})\\
=& P(0, r_0, T) + \int_0^t\partial_s P(s, r_s, T) ds + \int_0^t\partial_r P(s, r_s, T) dr_s^c + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \int_0^t r_s\partial_{rr} P(s, r_s, T)ds\\
& \quad +\sum_{s \leq t}\big[P(s, r_s, T) - P(s, r_{s-}, T) \big] \quad (\mbox{where } dr_t^c = \kappa(\theta - r_t)dt + \sigma \sqrt{r_t} d W_t)\\
=&  P(0, r_0, T) + \int_0^t\partial_s P(s, r_s, T) ds + \int_0^t\partial_r P(s, r_s, T) dr_s^c + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \int_0^t r_s\partial_{rr} P(s, r_s, T)ds\\
& \quad +\int_0^t \int_{\mathbb{R}}\big[ P(s, r_{s-}+y, T) - P(s, r_{s-}, T)\big]\mu(ds, dy) \quad (\mbox{where } \mu = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \delta_{\tau_i, J_i})\\
=&  P(0, r_0, T) + \int_0^t\partial_s P(s, r_s, T) ds + \int_0^t\partial_r P(s, r_s, T) dr_s^c + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \int_0^t r_s\partial_{rr} P(s, r_s, T)ds\\
&\quad  +\int_0^t \int_{\mathbb{R}}\big[P(s, r_{s-}+y, T) - P(s, r_{s-}, T)\big](\mu(ds, dy) - ds v(dy)) \\
&\quad  +\int_0^t ds\int_{\mathbb{R}}\big[ P(s, r_s+y, T) - P(s, r_s, T)\big]\lambda f_J(y)dy,
\end{align*}
where $v(dy) = \lambda f_J(y)dy$. Here 
\begin{align*}
M_t = \int_0^t \int_{\mathbb{R}}\big[ u(X_{s-} + y, s) - u(X_{s-}, s))\big](\mu(ds, dy) - ds v(dy))
\end{align*}
is a martingale. Since $P(t, r_t, T) e^{-\int_0^t r_s ds}$ is a martingale, and
\begin{align*}
d\Big(P(t, r_t, T) e^{-\int_0^t r_s ds}\Big) &= e^{-\int_0^t r_s ds}\big[-r_t P(t, r_t, T) dt + dP(t, r_t, T)\big],
\end{align*}
we obtain that
\begin{align*}
&-r_t P(t, r_t, T) + \partial_t P(t, r_t, T) + \kappa(\theta-r_t)\partial_r P(t, r_t, T)
+ \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 r_t\partial_{rr} P(t, r_t, T) \\
& \qquad\qquad + \int_{\mathbb{R}}\big[ P(t, r_t+y, T) - P(t, r_t, T\big]\lambda f_J(y)dy = 0.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
& \partial_t P(t, r_t, T) + \kappa(\theta-r_t)\partial_r P(t, r_t, T)
+ \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 r_t\partial_{rr} P(t, r_t, T) -(r_t+\lambda)P(t, r_t, T)\\
& \qquad\qquad + \lambda \int_{\mathbb{R}} P(t, r_t+y, T) f_J(y)dy = 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You claim that $P(t, r_t, T) e^{-\int_0^t r_s ds}$ is a martingale, but under which measure ?

Comment: It is under the risk-neutral measure.

Comment: So, shouldn't be a market price of risk parameter in your equation ?

Comment: We assume that all models are under the risk-neutral measure. Note that, the short rate is not a trading asset. Then, as long as the bond price is specified properly, the deflated bond price is a martingale, under the risk-neutral measure. See also discussions in [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18185/whats-risk-neutral-in-an-interest-rate-model/18186#18186).

Comment: Is there any good reference to an article/book where this is explained? Especially, the part when you need to define which terms has to sum up to 0. What happens with the diffusion terms?

Comment: The book [Financial Modeling](https://www.amazon.com/Financial-Modeling-Stochastic-Differential-Perspective-ebook/dp/B00D9KEPHM) by Stephane Crepey is helpful. For other parts, you may ask as another question.